# Create GUID constants? (VB.net)

Tags: .net, vb.net, controls, guid, com-interop

`Public Const ClassId = "92A1377A-7A3C-4FAF-94DA-C229AFFCFB12"
 Public Const InterfaceId = "2DE393C7-300A-46DB-B33C-583B2765C2F9"
 Public Const EventsId = "5452FC4D-C0C2-4E2B-87CA-8F43EAA14998"`

I found this in a code snippet and need to create my own GUID in vb.net.
But I didn't find a way that the program automatically creates constantes like this and shows them in the code. How can I do that? 
I'm not yet familiar with GUIDs but I suppose there were created automatically.

Thanks for any hints :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First point is that you cannot apply `const` modifier to GUID's as `const` is applied on primitive datatype. If you want you can use `Shared ReadOnly`.

Second point is you can refer [Guid.NewGuid Method ()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.guid.newguid(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1) which is used to create GUID. Something like

```
Dim str = Guid.NewGuid.ToString()
```

**EDIT:**

A good [MSDN reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/x66s8zcd.aspx) which you have found yourself can be helpful.

Comment: Thanks for your reply :) I just used the NewGuid Method but I don't get why I only get one ID and in this code snippet there are three for Class, Interface and Events :/ Any clue?

Comment: Just found this one. https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/x66s8zcd.aspx 

There is describe how to use the com class template. By using this it automatically generates the constants like I posted above.

Thanks for your help and sorry for taking your time :)

Comment: @Dyrdek:- Yes the link looks good and should solve your purpose. And no need to be sorry. Happy coding!

Comment: @Dyrdek:- I have updated the link in my answer so as it may help others as well in future.

Comment: nitpick: since this is a question about VB.Net, it should be `Shared ReadOnly`, not `static readonly`

Comment: And the semi-colons at the end of the lines won't compile either.

Comment: @MattWilko:- Thats not a big thing to understand. However I will update both the changes

Comment: Actually your example does not work at all. `Dim myguid As New Guid()` create a new Guid object with all zeros, so `.ToString` on that *always* produces `00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000`. What you actually want is `Dim str = Guid.NewGuid.ToString()`

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you can use `GuidGen` to create a new unique GUID for you:

```
Using menu TOOLS -> External Tools... add:
%Installation Path%\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\Tools\guidgen.exe
```

e.g.

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\Tools\guidgen.exe
```

Give it a title of `GUID Generator`

Then you can run this to create a Guid String for yourself. Select option 4 (Registry Format)

Once you have created a guid, you can assign it to a constant string in your code:

```
Const MyGuidString = "{1606C5C9-9ECA-4227-9F7E-7FA032D153BE}"
```

This is however just a string. If you want to use it as an actual Guid, you can define a variable like this:

```
Dim guidObject = New Guid(MyGuidString)
```